# Deploy error in WebLogic 10.3.6

Tags: deployment, weblogic

I have tried to make the dynamic web project according to Struts 2 tutorial today.
I have successfully build and then exported WAR file.
When I try to deploy my exported WAR in Eclipse in WebLogic server, after uploaded the WAR file and click next, it shows below:

```
unable to access the selected application. 
error exception in appmerge flows' progression
.....
```

- WebLogic server 10.3.4
- Struts2-2.5.10.1
- JSP
- JDK 1.6
- Eclipse Mars

Comment: Solved. See https://community.oracle.com/thread/3950362

Comment: Solved. I have amended maven pom.xml about the jar version and maven update again. It solved. Thanks